# Different forms of the Einstein field equation

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am working my way through the wonderfully written introduction "General relativity for mathematicians"  by Sachs & Wu. I am indeed a mathematics student and find this book to be well suited to the biases that entails. However there is one detail I have observed in which it differs from all expositions of general relativity I have seen and this is what I would like to get clarified.

The Einstein field equations are stated there in the form
$$
\mathbf G =\mathbf T + \mathbf E
$$
where $\mathbf G = \mathbf{Ric} - \frac 12 \mathbf{g} S$ is the Einstein tensor, $\mathbf T$ is the stress-energy tensor corresponding to matter (and hence depending on the particular matter model chosen) and $\mathbf E$ is the stress-energy tensor induced by an electromagnetic field $\mathbf F$ as
$$
\widetilde{\mathbf E} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\left(\frac 14\operatorname{tr}(\widetilde{\mathbf F}^2)I-\widetilde{\mathbf F}^2\right)
$$
where I am keeping to the notational conventions of the book and $\widetilde {\mathbf F}$ is the $(1,1)$-tensor physically equivalent to the $(0,2)$-tensor field $\mathbf F,$ viewed point-wise as a linear map $TM\to TM.$

However in nearly all other sources I checked the equation had the form
$$
\mathbf{G}=8\pi \mathbf T
$$
for some stress-energy field $\mathbf T,$ not necessarily corresponding only to matter. Consering this I have the following questions:

**Q1.** If I understand correctly, this $\mathbf T$ is just the sum $\mathbf T +\mathbf E$ above. So Sachs and Wu are just writing out this tensor in two parts to account for the contribution of two distinct soures of effects on spacetime; that of matter and that of electromagnetism. *Why is that not the standard practice among physicists*? Are there perhaps in general more than just these two sources of effects on spacetime?

**Q2.** There is no factor $8\pi$ in the Wu-Sachs version of the field equation. *Why is it missing?* I do not suppose this has to do with the systematic use of geometric units? Or maybe Wu and Sachs are just considering all the basic objects such as $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf T$ scaled by $8\pi$ in comparison to the standard conventions? But that does not seem to be the case either, because I have seen the very same definition of the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor in sources which include $8\pi$ in the field equation ...

Any help in clearing up this matter will be deeply appreciated!

P.S: I hope this is not an inappropriate question for this site and if it is, I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: I do not know why Sachs and Wu are treating the electromagnetic contribution separately from the other matters sources, but this is indeed non-standard. I think the physics convention is more natural, since the Einstein field equations are $G=T$, and the words associated with this equation is that the presence of matter ($T$) warps spacetime ($G$).

Q2: It's fairly common in mathematical physics for factors of $2$ and $\pi$ to be dropped by Mathematicians. The factor of $8\pi G$ perhaps make the field equations a bit messy, but it's natural from a physics point of view. See, for example: http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2014/03/13/einstein-and-pi/ for a nice take on this.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and to-the-point answer! The Einstein and pi article was also a pleasent little read. So if I understand clearly, a physicist would consider electromagnetism as somehow coming from matter and not having an independent existence?

Comment: Ah, welcome! Yes, a physicist would say that the system is Einstein gravity plus whatever matter you'd like to consider. Electromagnetism is simply one of many options (and I suspect Sachs and Wu treated it differently because it's one of the more well studied fields regarding it's coupling to gravity).